# Facebook PHP SDK - Profile Picture

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to get the profile picture for each user stored in my database session who has an account with my app. Basically on first use the app checks if the user exists in the database. If the user doesn't I store their Facebook ID and other information to use in tandem with information that will be created within the app.

I'm authenticating using the JavaScript SDK and pass that session on to PHP through a redirect. Okay, That works and all. But when I use the foreach statement to get each users picture by changing the id in the Facebook request... it works but it returns silhouette's even for my profile which is an actual account.

```
  foreach ($Pets as $Pet){
      //var_dump($Pets);
      $PetID = $Pet->ID;
      $request = new FacebookRequest(
           $_SESSION['fb_session'],
          'GET',
          '/'.$PetID.'/picture',
          array (
                 'redirect' => false,
                 'height' => '100',
                 'type' => 'square',
                 'width' => '100',
          )
      );
   $response = $request->execute();
   $UserPic = $response->getGraphObject();
   var_dump($response);
```

```
object(Facebook\FacebookResponse)[16]
  private 'request' => 
    object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)[2]
      private 'session' => 
        object(Facebook\FacebookSession)[4]
          private 'accessToken' => 
            object(Facebook\Entities\AccessToken)[5]
              ...
          private 'signedRequest' => null
      private 'method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
      private 'path' => string '/1396315913962347/picture' (length=25)
      private 'params' => 
        array (size=6)
          'redirect' => boolean false
          'height' => string '100' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'square' (length=6)
          'width' => string '100' (length=3)
          'access_token' => string 'CAAH2GhjyZB3UBAMJ4iPcr5MhC1cUwKHo31o6eeZCicTyA5eY5k3M1FR1Jyd24gjxy3tZBAS2NbgV9ZAdg8PouZCKEJ3xtDGz4FApLlHBvMhrH9yt1Wgc7G6MNWrb3axHrMmjsuJVn53N8SNQC0IBaUbRMaWnbRGwvMvZB8CFZAEBgLRhiUZAAwgTqSnbgizBHZCKlsvb2ClYtXqV94acbm1bGwCdfMQLC6SMZD' (length=231)
          'appsecret_proof' => string '4d12e86815d05cdcebf2602c1934cb6c70253c0db33447dcf963cd83df061d45' (length=64)
      private 'version' => string 'v2.2' (length=4)
      private 'etag' => null
  private 'responseData' => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'data' => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'is_silhouette' => boolean true
          public 'url' => string 'https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif' (length=64)
  private 'rawResponse' => string '{"data":{"is_silhouette":true,"url":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yo\/r\/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif"}}' (length=111)
  private 'etagHit' => boolean false
  private 'etag' => string '"c36341065b1906944a6c84a7c1c48e2f01e0c734"' (length=42)
```

How do I get the actual profile picture url and not the silhouette? I've already changed a test user's profile picture and tried to retrieve my own but all I get is silhouettes. Am I doing something wrong?